# Set Timeout while publishing the message in rabbit mq

Tags: c#, .net-core, rabbitmq

The below snippet publishes the message in RabbitMq.

```
var properties = channel.CreateBasicProperties();
                properties.Persistent = true;
                properties.DeliveryMode = (byte)deliveryMode;
                properties.Timestamp =  new AmqpTimestamp(Convert.ToInt64((DateTime.UtcNow.Subtract(new DateTime(1970, 1, 1))).TotalSeconds));

                _logger.LogTrace("Publishing event to Queue: {EventId} with Timestamp: {Timestamp}", integrationEvent.Id, properties.Timestamp);

                channel.BasicPublish(
                      exchange: exchangeName,
                      routingKey: routingKey,
                      mandatory: true,
                      basicProperties: properties,
                      body: body
                      );

                channel.ConfirmSelect();
```

I want to set the timeout when the message get published.

Comment: Can you please clarify? What is it that you wish to have time out?

Comment: Also, setting confirm after the publish doesn’t make a whole lot of sense.